# Is iOS 11.3 safari reporting scrolled fixed position incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ios11

There used to be a bug in iOS 11.2 in which the cursor in a scrolled fixed position text input would not be positioned in the input:

[Hackernoon Article about iOS 11.2 Bug](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8)

That seems to be fixed in iOS 11.3 but seems to be replaced by another bug in which getBoundingClientRect is reporting the wrong position of an element in a fixed div when the keyboard is open, see my example:

[Positioning example](https://kevindurb.github.io/ios11-3-issue/)

[(Source Code)](https://github.com/kevindurb/ios11-3-issue)

In my example I have an input inside a fixed position div and a box is being positioned on top of the input, it works correctly in all browsers but in iOS 11.3 once you put focus into the input the box moves vertically away from the input, and it seems to be related to the amount you are scrolling.

Is this a known issue?

Is there a work around for this?

EDIT: I have added screenshots of the issue to the github link